# How do I bind a mapped function?

Tags: javascript

I'm just messing with some code here to better understand JavaScript so don't ask me why I want to do this or provide alternate solutions. I'm looking for a reasoning of why this isn't working or what I'm doing wrong.

```
function print(item) {
  console.log(this[item]);
  return undefined
}
```

The above function is a very simple one. Now, when I map this onto an array of keys of an object and provide the object as the `this` value to map, it prints the values of the keys which is perfect.

```
Object.keys(hello).map(print, hello);
```

Now, let's say that I want to assign the above to a property of an object.

```
var hello = {
  10: 100,
  20: 200,
  30: 300,
  40: 400,
  50: 500
};
```

I can't obviously just do the following.

```
hello.print =  Object.keys(hello).map(print, hello);
```

Because that would assign the result of calling map and would result in an array whose every item would be undefined since I have returned undefined irrespective of item in the function.

Hence, I think I should be binding a variant of the above function call to `hello.print` so that I can then just call `hello.print()` so I try the following.

```
hello.print = Object.keys(hello).map.bind(hello, print, hello);
```

Now, I suppose that should (in my knowledge and opinion) bind a version of map (which calls print on hello and obviously bind also takes a value for this so I've sent in hello twice) to the object.

This does not work. Tell me why. Please.

http://jsbin.com/zebikuwe/1/edit

Comment: Why are you returning undefined? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just don't return `undefined` but the property value?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact the function still has a `console.log()` which should be executed irrespective. I return undefined because I don't care about the array that map returns. Let's just say that for now, I am using `map` as if it was `forEach` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> hello.print = Object.keys(hello).map.bind(hello, print, hello);
> ```
>
> Now, I suppose that should (in my knowledge and opinion) bind a version of map (which calls print on hello and obviously bind also takes a value for this so I've sent in hello twice) to the object.

Yes, and it does. Only that it does [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `map` to `hello`, while the original call does apply [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `Object.keys(hello)` array - it's [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the method call. So you need to do

```
hello.print = Array.prototype.map.bind(Object.keys(hello), print, hello);
```

Comment: So, essentially the `this` value for a `map` needs to be the array that it is applied on? Well, yes that makes perfect sense. Would there be any other way to bind `map` the way I did without having to send in `this` so that it would still be in the context of the array it is being run on? I know that a `this` value for `bind` is compulsory. But any way I can retain more of the syntactical structure in my question? That is, without having to access map out of the prototype and accessing it out of the array it is to be called on, instead?

Comment: No, you need to use `bind` on the `map` function, or use a function expression like @Nit did in his now deleted answer. However, you don't need to access the `map` function via the prototype explicitly, you could also write `[].map` or `Object.keys(…).map` - as long as you then bind it as a method to the `Object.keys(hello)` array. Edit: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Okay, that clears things. But `Object.keys(hello).map.bind(Object.keys(hello), print, hello);` does not work while it should according to the above comment. http://jsbin.com/fezedara/1/edit

Comment: Works well for me. You just have to call the bound function…

Comment: Oops. Stupid mistake. Forgot to call it in the jsbin as well. Sorry! And thank you for you help.