# Why is this property printed in one instance and not in a similiar one even though it is enumerable in both?

Tags: javascript

In the code that follows (this is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219781/how-do-i-bind-a-mapped-function) one but has nothing to do with that one) I am basically assigning a function to the property of an object. And the function itself essentially prints the keys of all the properties in the object.

```
function print(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

var hello = {
  10: 100,
  20: 200,
  30: 300,
  40: 400,
  50: 500
};

hello.print = function () {
  Object.keys(hello).map(print, this);
};

hello.print();
```

In the above instance, the function prints its own key as well as expected. http://jsbin.com/bujutefa/1/edit

However, in the following scenario, it does not.

```
hello.print = Array.prototype.map.bind(Object.keys(hello), print, hello);

hello.print();
```

http://jsbin.com/fezedara/1/edit

I don't see why the two situations differ. I have checked to see whether print is enumerable or not. It is enumerable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it.

In the first scenario, the `Object.keys()` is evaluated when the function is called and hence includes `print` as well.

In the second scenario, the expression on the right is evaluated before the function is called naturally and the resulting function is thus already bound to the array of `Object.keys()` as it was before the evaluation and assignment is complete. Thus, even though when the function is called, `print` is an enumerable property, it is not printed since the function that is being called, is bound an array returned by Object.keys() at a point during execution when `print` was not yet a property and thus does not include `print`.

Comment: I figured out the answer to my question but am not deleting it since it might help someone else in the future.